# Using D3 axis functionality on a canvas

Tags: d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an axis on a canvas using D3 functionality (as exampled here https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/axes-in-d3). However every example I've seen is using an SVG while I wish to use canvas. On the other hand I didn't see any indication, in their documentation or elsewhere, that it can't be done in canvas.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

In short: no, that's not possible.

D3 is pretty much render agnostic, meaning it can be used to create SVG, Canvas, other HTML elements etc. However, some modules are indeed quite specific, and that's the case of [`d3-axis`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis).

If you have a look at `d3-axis` [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/a9b688e4b0885fc4f855b7c12816ae64d82bdf23/src/axis.js#L61) you'll see that it append SVG `<path>`, `<line>` and `<text>` elements for creating the axis. For instance:

```
path.enter().insert("path", ".tick")
```

Finally, [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/2) you have a discussion on this subject, where Bostock (D3 creator) abandons the idea of modifying the `d3-axis` module for creating axes on HTML canvas.